# how to sort array in ruby by multi-field

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, hash

I have an array like:

```
-  
        {"name"=>“A”, "10"=>30, "2" =>40, "90"=>0}
        {"name"=>“B”, "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>0}
        {"name"=>“C”, "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>10}

---
```

I suppose to first sort by highest key (90):

```
- 
        {"name"=>"C", "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>10}
        {"name"=>"A", "10"=>30, "2" =>40, "90"=>0}
        {"name"=>"B", "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>0}
```

then sort by next higher key (10, in numerical order):

```
- 
        {"name"=>"C", "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>10}
        {"name"=>"A", "10"=>30, "2" =>40, "90"=>0}
        {"name"=>"B", "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>0}
```

then sort by next higher key 2:

How could I achieve it in ruby?

### ---

#### Updated:

The keys are not defined, for example, it could be 50, 10,2. But it would sort from highest to lowest.

### I know if the keys are defined (e.g.):

```
a = [{:x=>3,:y=>2,:z=>1},{:x=>3,:y=>1,:z=>3},{:x=>1,:y=>3,:z=>2}]

a.sort_by do |p|
    [p[:x],p[:z]]
```

### end

we could do that, but confused about what should I do if the keys are undefined (like, could I do an iteration inside the sort?)

So, overall, I want to sort by all numerical value from highest to lowest.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  One important point: you should demonstrate the code that you've written to solve your problem.

Comment: Your sort by key '10' isn't sorted as expected. Do you want three separate sorts, or a single sort on all three keys in descending order of priority? Will the keys always be '90', '10', and '2', or are they arbitrary?

Comment: @moveson The sort by key '10' is exactly what is expected as a secondary sort key. Your question about key names is valid though.

Comment: Note that the values of the "name" key are invalid. Are they supposed to be strings? Do you want to sort numerically? If so, why are those keys strings?

Comment: Hint: Please [edit] your question to answer the above concerns.

Comment: my comment was removed as I thought the example preceded the definition; the lack of the `2` example threw me off when quickly skimming the question

Comment: When you give an example ensure that all inputs are valid Ruby objects. A "list of hashes" is not. Instead write `arr = [{"name"=>C, "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>10}, {...}, {...}]`, and refer to it as "an array of hashes". Notice that I assigned a variable `arr` to the array. That way readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it (and all readers will refer to the same variable). This also facilitates cut-and-paste. I suggest you edit as some readers downvote questions that do not contain valid Ruby objects.

Comment: Your question is unclear: why is `'10'` the next highest key after `'90'`? `'2'` is *greater than* `'10'`! Also, is `'name'` higher or lower than `'2'`? And why? Also, even though it doesn't matter for the answer to the question, you should either define `A`, `B`, and `C` or (preferred) replace them with literal stand-ins, so that someone who wants to answer your question can just copy&paste your test cases instead of every single person who tries to answer your question having to figure out over and over and over again what `A`, `B`, and `C` might be.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that

- as in the example, all elements (hashes) of `arr` have the same keys;
- `A`, `B` and `C` are intended to be literals (e.g., strings or symbols), so I've changed them to `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"`; and
- by "...by the highest key..." you mean "...by the key other than `'name'` which is largest after having been converted to an integer...". Whereas `10 > 2 #=> true`, `"10" > "2" #=> false`.

The array is therefore the following.

```
arr = [{ "name"=>"A", "10"=>30, "2" =>40, "90"=>0 },
       { "name"=>"B", "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>0 },
       { "name"=>"C", "10"=>20, "2" =>40, "90"=>10 }]
```

This is one way to perform the sort.

```
keys = (arr.first.keys - ["name"]).sort_by(&:to_i).reverse
  #=> ["90", "10", "2"]
arr.sort_by { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }
  #=> [{"name"=>"B", "10"=>20, "2"=>40, "90"=>0},
  #    {"name"=>"A", "10"=>30, "2"=>40, "90"=>0},
  #    {"name"=>"C", "10"=>20, "2"=>40, "90"=>10}]
```

By way of example, `sort_by`'s block calculation for `arr[0]` is

```
{ "name"=>"A", "10"=>30, "2" =>40, "90"=>0 }.values_at(*keys)
  #=> { "name"=>"A", "10"=>30, "2" =>40, "90"=>0 }.values_at("90", "10",  "2") 
  #=> [0, 30, 40]
```

See [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (paragraph 3) for an explanation of how arrays of the same size are compared. See also [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I looking for! may I also ask if I want to sort it in descending order, how could I add comparator into the sort_by like java? I see the normal way is:arr.sort_by{ |a| -a[:bar] } }. But this trick seems could not apply in this case? thanks!

Comment: ohh, find the way to use reverse function.

Comment: This does sort in descending order of keys converted to integers. That's why `.reverse` is there. If you want to sort in ascending order just remove `.reverse`. I don't know java, so can't help with the rest of your question. Perhaps a reader can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can iterate inside `sort_by`:

```
# first sort the arbitrary integer keys in reverse order (assuming those keys will be same across all hashes)
keys = a[0].
         keys. # ["name", "10", "2", "90"]
         select { |k| k.match?(/^\d+$/) }. # this will basically keep only the integer valued strings: ["10", "2", "90"]
         sort_by(&:to_i). # this will sort them by their integer values: ["2", "10", "90"]
         reverse # ["90", "10", "2"]: this is the order by which you want to sort the hashes

# now use this ordered `keys` to sort the hashes by corresponding values
a.sort_by { |p| keys.map { |x| p[x] } }.reverse
```